# Mac ping but only display avg ms

Tags: macos, bash, terminal

What I want is to ping a server but only want the avg time to be returned, I think grep or something like that would help but a google search doesn't return much useful.

This is to go into a geektool script that will display a servers ping for me to see if its up.

Needs to be a script / command that will work in terminal as I need to pull it over to python as well.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow on my system ping command doesn't output `round-trip` but `rtt`.
So this one is going to work better:

```
ping -q -c 5 google.com | tail -n 1 | cut -f 5 -d '/'
```

`-q` makes it less verbose because we don't need much of the output anyway. `tail` simply returns the last line of the output

Answer (score 1):

How about something like:

```
ping -c 5 google.com | grep "round-trip" | cut -f 5 -d "/"
```